# Creating an alarm application using Expo and React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, alarm, expo-notifications, expo-calendar

I want to create a React Native alarm application on Expo. I want the alarm to ring at the set time, whether I am in the app or not. The alarm should stop either when I press a stop button or when the user moves the phone. I can create events in the calendar using Expo Calendar. However, the alarm doesn't ring for a long time. It comes as a notification. The alarm should ring until the user dismisses it or moves the phone.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { TextInput, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Button } from "react-native";
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import * as Calendar from "expo-calendar";

const AddAlarm = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("date");
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [value, onChangeText] = useState("");

  const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate;
    setShow(false);
    setDate(currentDate);
  };

  const showMode = (currentMode) => {
    setShow(true);
    setMode(currentMode);
  };

  const showDatepicker = () => {
    showMode("date");
  };

  const showTimepicker = () => {
    showMode("time");
  };

  const handleDatePicked = async () => {
    const { status } = await Calendar.requestCalendarPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      alert("Takvim izni verilmedi!");
      return;
    }

    const defaultCalendar = await Calendar.getCalendarsAsync();
    const alarmTime = date.getTime();
    const eventDetails = {
      title: value,
      startDate: new Date(alarmTime),
      endDate: new Date(alarmTime),
      timeZone: "local",
      reminderMinutes: 0,
      alarms: [{ relativeOffset: 0, method: Calendar.AlarmMethod.ALERT }],
    };

    await Calendar.createEventAsync(defaultCalendar[0].id, eventDetails);
    console.log("Alarm set for:", date.toLocaleString());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onChangeText("");
    setDate(new Date());
  }, []);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
      }}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          marginLeft: 10,
          marginRight: 10,
          height: 40,
          marginTop: 10,
        }}
        onPress={showDatepicker}
      >
        {date ? (
          <Text>{date.toLocaleDateString()}</Text>
        ) : (
          <Text>Tarih Seçiniz</Text>
        )}

        <Icon name="calendar" size={30} color="gray" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#ccc",
          marginVertical: 10,
          marginHorizontal: 10,
        }}
      ></View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          marginLeft: 10,
          marginRight: 10,
          height: 40,
        }}
        onPress={showTimepicker}
      >
        {date ? (
          <Text>{date.toLocaleTimeString()}</Text>
        ) : (
          <Text>Saat Seçiniz</Text>
        )}
        <Icon name="calendar" size={30} color="gray" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#ccc",
          marginVertical: 10,
          marginHorizontal: 10,
        }}
      ></View>
      <TextInput
        editable
        multiline
        numberOfLines={4}
        placeholder="Açıklama"
        onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
        value={value}
        style={{ padding: 10, borderWidth: 1, margin: 10, borderColor: "#ccc" }}
      />
      {show && (
        <DateTimePicker
          testID="dateTimePicker"
          value={date}
          mode={mode}
          is24Hour={true}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      )}
      <View
        style={{
          marginBottom: 50,
          flex: 1,
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          justifyContent: "flex-end",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Button onPress={handleDatePicked} title="Kaydet" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AddAlarm;
```